# How to save the Object returned from the query.exec() function in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoose.
Here is my scenario:

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });
var parentSchema = new Schema({
children: [childSchema]});
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
```

Say I have created a parent 'p' with children, and I am querying for 'p', using

```
var query = Parent.find({"_id":"562676a04787a98217d1c81e"});
query.select('children');                                   
query.exec(function(err,person){                            
    if(err){                                                    
        return console.error(err);                               
    } else {                                                     
        console.log(person);                                     
    }
});
```

I need to access the person object outside the async function. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongoose's **[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find)** method is **[asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/122005)** which means you should use a callback that you can wrap the query from the **[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find)** method. For example, in your case, you can define a callback as

```
function getChildrenQuery(parentId, callback){
    Parent.find({"_id": parentId}, "children", function(err, docs){
        if (err) {
          callback(err, null);
        } else {
          callback(null, docs);
        }
    }); 
}
```

which you can then call like this:

```
var id = "562676a04787a98217d1c81e";
getChildrenQuery(id, function(err, children) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    // do something with children
    children.forEach(function(child){
      console.log(child.name);
    });
});
```

Another approach you may take is that of promises where the **[`exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec)** method returns a **[Promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise)**, so you can do the following:

```
function getChildrenPromise(parentId){
   var promise = Parent.find({_id: parentId}).select("children").exec();
   return promise;
}
```

Then, when you would like to get the data, you should make it async:

```
var promise = getChildrenPromise("562676a04787a98217d1c81e");
promise.then(function(children){
    children.forEach(function(child){
        console.log(child.name);
    });
}).error(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access it outside of the callback (="the async function" you mentioned). That's how node.js works:

- your call to the database will take some time - a very long time when you compare it to just execute a simple code statement.
- Node.js is non-blocking, so it will not wait for the database to return the result, and it wlll continue immediately by executing the code after your query.exec statement.
- so the code you write after the query.exec statement is run BEFORE the database returns the result, it is therefore impossible to use that result there.

BUT... embrace async programming:

- just write all the code you need into the "async function"
- pass a callback into your function, call it from "the async function" and pass it the query result